# How to Add Segue When Clicking a Button go to Another Controller: Validation Logic

Tags: controller, uikit, interface-builder, uistoryboard, segue

Imagine that I have a viewcontrol class (and it has login information) and what I want to do is: after the user clicks the login button, I want to check it with my validation method and then I want to go to the `UITabBarController` in the storyboard.

Can anyone help me add the segue for `UITabBarController`? If I add a push segue on the login button, it will go to `UITabBarController` directly irrespective of the validation status.

Answer (score 3):

you can tie your button from your storyboard to an IBAction in your initial view controller.

then you can create a push segue (named "pushToTabBarController" for reference in this answer) from that same view controller to the UITabBarController

finally, in the IBAction code for your login button, you can validate, and if happy with the validation, then call

```
- (IBAction) validateThenPush:(id)sender
{
    if ([self loginValidated])
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToTabBarController" sender:self];
}
```

(sender:self can be nil or the button passed to the action or whatever you want for context in `prepareForSegue:sender:`)